# Internuclear Binding Force: Experimental geometric detail

Tags: specific-reference, scattering-cross-section, strong-force, nuclear-physics

I am looking for *the* most precise currently available deuterium potential energy curve (generated purely by experimental data) on the nucleon-nucleon scale. This is *crucial.* I need a radial cross-section from experiment, *not* theory. Would someone who is experienced in resourcefulness please direct me to an original, highly precise and accurate (and credible) source that is up-to-date?

Comment: If this is for a research project, have you asked your adviser for a reference first? He/she may be able to give you a quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

Either the Nijmegen or Argonne v18 potentials are "realistic," meaning that they fit the two-body (pp,np) scattering data up to 350 MeV lab with $\chi^2$ per datum ~ 1.  Using their names you can search online and the literature.